# j2me openOutputStream stream already open

Tags: blackberry, post, java-me, outputstream, httpconnection

Im having difficulties with the HttpConnection posting data to my server. The first time everything goes well. The second time it says; 'Stream already open', but i close everything after the response.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.location.*;
import java.io.*;

class GetSnowheights
{    
    HttpConnection http = null;
    QualifiedCoordinates q = null;
    public String result = "Geen data";
    private boolean running;

    public GetSnowheights(QualifiedCoordinates q) {        
        try
        {
            /*
            this.http = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://www.diamond4it.nl/bb/");                
            this.http.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
            this.http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            */
            //Internet.getInstance();
            this.http = Internet.getConnection();
        }catch(Exception err){
           err.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.q = q;
        this.result = "Running";
    }

    public void GetResult(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();        
        this.result = "GetResult";

        if(this.http != null){

            OutputStream os = null;
            InputStream is = null;
            try
            {
                //Send request
                os = this.http.openOutputStream();
                String data = "lat=1&lng=1";
                //String data = "lat=" + this.q.getLatitude() + "&lng=" + this.q.getLongitude();
                os.write(data.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                this.result = "dataSend";                

                //Check response and read data
                int res = this.http.getResponseCode();
                this.result = "Result: " + res;
                if(res == 200){
                    is = this.http.openInputStream();
                    int ch;
                    // Check the Content-Length first 
                    long len = this.http.getLength();
                    if(len!=-1) { 
                        for(int i = 0;i<len;i++){
                            if((ch = is.read())!= -1){
                                sb.append((char)ch);
                            }
                        }
                    } else { 
                        // if the content-length is not available 
                        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1){
                            sb.append((char)ch); 
                        }
                    }
                    is.close();
                }

                this.result = sb.toString();

            }catch(Exception err){
                //err.printStackTrace();
                this.result = err.toString() + "\r\n" + err.getMessage();
            }finally{
                if(is != null){
                    try{
                        is.close();
                    }catch(Exception err){
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if(os != null){
                    try{
                        //os.flush();
                        os.close();
                    }catch(Exception err){
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                /*
                if(http != null){
                    try{
                        http.close();
                    }catch(Exception err){
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                */
            }

        }else{
            this.result = "No connection";
        }
    }    

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to reuse `this.http`?  That is, do you call `GetResult()` more than once without getting a new `HttpConnection`?  I don't think that that is allowed.

Comment: Well its a Singleton Class Internet which returns a valid httpconnection. The this.http a private one in this class, so yes i reuse it.

Comment: OK, so you call `GetResult()` more than one time for each instance of the `GetSnowheights` class?  That would mean that you are trying to reuse the `HttpConnection`.  I've never done that myself, but it strikes me as a potential problem.  What if you refactor your code to create a new `GetSnowheights` instance before every call of `GetResult()`?

Answer (score 0):

2 ideas:

1. Why have you commented out the `http.close()` in `finally` block? We should always close HttpConnections.
2. Don't you call `GetResult()` from several threads simultaneously? If yes, then make the method synchronized by adding `synchronized` keyword in its definition.

P.S. I find the design of the class a bit misleading. It's very easy to make a mistake by incorrect usage of it. I'd combine `GetSnowheights` and `GetResult` into the only synchronized method.

Comment: Nope not working. Still the same message. Even with sinchronized void

Comment: Then I just don't know what to propose.